# xPath - sum(//*) explained

Tags: xml, xpath

Lets say we have the following XML structure:

```
<a><b>2<d>4</d></b><c>3</c></a>
```

Why does `sum(//*)` return 274?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it's 243 + 24 + 3 + 4 = 274

`//*` means all elements, which are `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`. Then, we summarize their text values, which include everything except tags.

I think, what you're looking for is `sum(//*/text())`, which is 9 in this case

Comment: Could you please expand on the logic behind these numbers a bit? I still find it difficult to grasp how it calculates 243 and 24.

Comment: `//*` gives you `['<a><b>2<d>4</d></b><c>3</c></a>', '<b>2<d>4</d></b>', '<d>4</d>', '<c>3</c>']`. From http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-sum "The sum function returns the sum, for each node in the argument node-set, of the result of converting the string-values of the node to a number."